# Sum operation performed on rows till specified value: a new row for each group for which the sum exceeds the specified value

Tags: sql

```
CREATE TABLE TEMP(RESOURCE_VALUE VARCHAR2(63 BYTE),TOT_COUNT NUMBER)
```

I want an query which can extract the range from which to which I want to have breakup of the sum records to XYZ value. I will  say 50,000 is the break up need. Then it has to display all the ranges from which RESOURCE_VALUE   to which RESOURCE_VALUE   I can get sum <=50,000. One RESOURCE_VALUE   value can be included in only one range.

Example: sample data 
The Below Is The input

```
resource_value | tot_count
---------------+----------
       1          100
       2          50
       3          20
       4          30
       5          300
       6          250
       7          200
       8          30
       9          60
       10         200
       11         110
       12         120
```

Then the output has to be something like this :

sample output 1: `when sum(tot_count)<=300`

```
start resource_value    endresource_value   sum
---------------------+---------------------+-------
       1                      4               300
       5                      5               300
       6                      6               250
       7                      9               290
       10                     10              200
       11                     12              230
```

sample output 2: when `sum(tot_count)<=500`

```
start resource_value    end resource_value  sum 
---------------------+---------------------+------
           1                   4             300
           5                   5             300
           6                   8             480
           9                   12            490
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just guess that you use `ORACLE`, because of your table structure, and in oracle you can use this query to get your aim:

```
with vw1(val,flg,sumval) as
(select 1 val,0 flg,TOT_COUNT sumval
from TEMP where RESOURCE_VALUE = '1'
union all
select vw1.val + 1 val,
case when vw1.sumval + t1.TOT_COUNT > 300 then vw1.flg + 1 else vw1.flg end flg,
case when vw1.sumval + t1.TOT_COUNT > 300 then t1.TOT_COUNT else vw1.sumval + t1.TOT_COUNT end sumval
From TEMP t1,vw1 WHERE t1.RESOURCE_VALUE = TO_CHAR(vw1.val + 1))
select min(val) START_RESOURCE_VALUE,max(val) END_RESOURCE_VALUE,
max(sumval) "SUM" from vw1 group by flg order by min(val);
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2c020/6)

Comment: Thanks a lot that give me a break through the issue.